# Cordova running into error while adding platform for ionic android

Tags: android, powershell, cordova, ionic-framework, cmd

I just started learning ionic app and everything was going on well till I have to add platform. I ran the following command:
`ionic cordova platform add android`
and this what I got:

```
> cordova.cmd platform add android
C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
operable program or batch file.as an internal or external command,

    at makeError (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:39:19)
    at osName (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
    at new RelentlessInsight (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:31:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:39:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) {
  code: 1,
  stdout: '',
  stderr: "'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n" +
    'operable program or batch file.\r\n',
  failed: true,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption',
  timedOut: false
}
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

After reading so many solutions online, I've uninstalled and reinstalled cordova and I still get similar error even when i try to check the version of cordova installed. I'll be glad if anyone can provide me with a working solution. Thanks.
After successfully setting up powershell7 core, this anothe error i ran into

````
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
The argument '(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption' is not recognized as the name of a script file. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.


Usage: pwsh[.exe] [-Login] [[-File] <filePath> [args]]
                  [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                                | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]
                  [-ConfigurationName <string>] [-CustomPipeName <string>]
                  [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
                  [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>] [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]
                  [-Interactive] [-MTA] [-NoExit] [-NoLogo] [-NonInteractive] [-NoProfile]
                  [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}] [-SettingsFile <filePath>] [-STA] [-Version]
                  [-WindowStyle <style>] [-WorkingDirectory <directoryPath>]

       pwsh[.exe] -h | -Help | -? | /?

PowerShell Online Help https://aka.ms/powershell-docs

All parameters are case-insensitive.

    at makeError (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:39:19)
    at osName (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
    at new RelentlessInsight (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:31:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Stephynoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:39:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) {
  code: 64,
  stdout: '\r\n' +
    'Usage: pwsh[.exe] [-Login] [[-File] <filePath> [args]]\r\n' +
    '                  [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]\r\n' +
    '                                | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]\r\n' +
    '                  [-ConfigurationName <string>] [-CustomPipeName <string>]\r\n' +
    '                  [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]\r\n' +
    '                  [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>] [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]\r\n' +
    '                  [-Interactive] [-MTA] [-NoExit] [-NoLogo] [-NonInteractive] [-NoProfile]\r\n' +
    '                  [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}] [-SettingsFile <filePath>] [-STA] [-Version]\r\n' +
    '                  [-WindowStyle <style>] [-WorkingDirectory <directoryPath>]\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '       pwsh[.exe] -h | -Help | -? | /?\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'PowerShell Online Help https://aka.ms/powershell-docs\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'All parameters are case-insensitive.\r\n',
  stderr: "The argument '(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption' is not recognized as the name of a script file. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.\r\n",
  failed: true,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption',
  timedOut: false
}```
````

Comment: Have you been modifying the content of your system `%PATH%` variable? The location of `powershell.exe` by default should be there, `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ `, or if you've installed a newer version, possibly `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\ `. If the entry is there, then perhaps you've broken your `%PATHEXT%` variable, which should include `.EXE`

Comment: I've done that but now in getting a new error

Comment: And the new error is a secret is it?

Comment: Compo, I've updated the error as seen

Comment: Your code suggests that a file named `cordova.cmd` is being invoked. and I'll assume that it is using the command `powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption`. However, your error message suggests that `powershell` is not a valid command, and provides an error message about `pwsh`. `pwsh` is usually used when your system is using PowerShell Core, version 6 and above. These versions use `pwsh.exe`, not `powershell.exe`, so perhaps you just need to change your command to `pwsh (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption`, instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I absolutely have no idea on how to do that. Can you provide me with direct instructions on how to do that.